# Getting size of string in function arguments

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass `string` to function.

I am getting:

```
Data:abcdefghijk
<br>size of Data:4
```

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
void trying (char *Data)
{
cout << "Data:" << Data;
cout << "\nsize of Data:" << sizeof(Data);

} 
main()
{
char DaTa[] = "abcdefghijk";

trying(DaTa);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always specify the language that you're working in as a tag for your question.

Comment: Looks ok ... what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although other members are being a bit obtuse in not inferring your intent, it would have been helpful if you had said you were seeking to obtain the size of the passed array.

Anyhoo ....

Within `trying()`, `sizeof(Data)` computes the size of a pointer, not the size of the array passed by the caller.

Given only a pointer, there is no way `trying()` can access the size of the array, because the pointer does not carry that information (it can point to one element or the first in an array, and there is no way to tell).   If you want `trying()` to access the number of elements in the array, you need to pass it separately (e.g. as a separate argument).